# Using ace-editor with readonly and small editable areas

Tags: readonly, ace-editor

I am trying to use ace-editor to write a code tutorial, so I need to have my code in the editor, but only allow the user to edit certain parts.
for example:

```
....
myfunction(1000);
...
```

where the user can only edit the values in parenthesis (1000).
I have tried using a combination of Anchors (for the 1000) and readonly in keyboard events, but the Anchor does not seem to work how you would like a template to work.

I would be grateful of any examples or suggested.

thanks in advance.

jon

Answer (score 0):

Anchors have undocumented `$insertRight` option see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/anchor.js#L134 which you can use for the first anchor.

another solution is to write something like [`updateMarkers`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/4b8a9a475bd1f3fd70013ceeb1573e23ab6276fd/lib/ace/keyboard/vim.js#L326) function in [vim.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/4b8a9a475bd1f3fd70013ceeb1573e23ab6276fd/lib/ace/keyboard/vim.js#L326)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still tricky to get this working, as you I can get anchors to work, but you can always seem to cursor back in to the zone and delete the last character - strange!

So my solution now is to make the whole area read-only, and hilight the editable areas, when the users clicks, pop up a dialog, not ideal but works well enough.

Comment: I had a similar problem, using the readonly/editable anchors. The user can delete the  last character of the editable anchor, leaving it in a no-edit mode because it touches the non editable anchors. My solution was wrapping the editable anchor in spaces and listening on the "input" event to restore them back if they get deleted. That way the user can't delete the last character. Hoping to hear for a better solution.